# What's the best way to find the Nth element of a type of item in a paged list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I'm rendering a list of items in a List like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <List>
      {() => {
        return items.map(item => {
          return (
            <ListItem
              key={item.id}
              item={item}
            />
          );
        });
      }}
    </List>
  );
}
```

and the item passed into ListItem can basically be two different types and I want to conditionally change it see comment in the example below

```
render() {
  const { item } = this.props
  switch (item.__typename) {
    case "TypeA":
      item = (
        <TypeAComponent item={item}/>
      );
      if (this is the second TypeA in the list) {
        item = <NewWrapper>{item}</NewWrapper>
      }
      break;
    case "TypeB":
      item = (
        <TypeBComponent item={item}/>
      );
      break;
  }
  return <ItemWrapper>{item}</ItemWrapper>
}
```

I can imagine that I do this calculation while mapping through items in the List render. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Do you know the Nth numerically?

Comment: Yup it'll be a constant at the top of the file like we can just say 5

Comment: One thing youa are passing item as data prop. Is that right or AM i missing something

Comment: Yup, that's right sorry typo

Answer (score 0):

You could change your first map loop to something like this:

```
render() {
  let itemACount = 0;
  return (
    <List>
      {items.map(item => {
          if(item.type === 'typeA') {
             if(itemACount === 0) {
                 itemACount ++;
                 return (<ItemWrapper><TypeAComponent item={item}/></ItemWrapper>)
             }
             return <ItemWrapper><NewWrapper>{item}</NewWrapper></ItemWrapper>
          }
          return (
            <ItemWrapper><TypeBComponent item={item}/></ItemWrapper>
          );
        });
      }
    </List>
  );
}
```